# AttributeError at /autocomplete/

Tags: python, django, solr, pycharm, django-haystack

I am trying to use autocomplete using haystack solr. And I am getting the following error for the code below:

views.py code:

```
import simplejson as json
from django.http import HttpResponse
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template.context_processors import csrf


def autocomplete(request):
    request=csrf(request)
    content_auto=request.GET.get('q', '')
    sqs = SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(content_auto)[:5]
    suggestions = [result.title for result in sqs]
    # Make sure you return a JSON object, not a bare list.
    # Otherwise, you could be vulnerable to an XSS attack.
    the_data = json.dumps({
        'results': suggestions
    })
    return HttpResponse(the_data, content_type='application/json')
```

The error which I am getting is given below(which is mostly for line 10 of views.py):

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'GET'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/autocomplete/
Django Version: 1.8.2
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'dict' object has no attribute 'GET'
Exception Location: C:\Users\hp user\PycharmProjects\solrven\solr\views.py in autocomplete, line 10
Python Executable:  C:\Users\hp user\solr27\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.9
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\hp user\\PycharmProjects\\solrven',
 'C:\\Users\\hp user\\PycharmProjects\\solrven',
 'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\hp user\\solr27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\hp user\\solr27\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\hp user\\solr27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Users\\hp user\\solr27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Users\\hp user\\solr27\\Scripts',
 'C:\\Python27\\Lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Users\\hp user\\solr27',
 'C:\\Users\\hp user\\solr27\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 23 Jun 2015 20:21:34 +0530
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

C:\Users\hp user\solr27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in get_response
                                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\hp user\PycharmProjects\solrven\solr\views.py in autocomplete
                content_auto=request.GET.get('q', '')
```

My app url looks like below:

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from . import views


urlpatterns = [
url(r'^autocomplete/$',views.autocomplete)
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line of your view replaces the `request` variable with a context dict containing a CSRF token. Don't do that.